# Redeclare a variable for convenience in golang?

Tags: go

This code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    var a bool
    var b interface{}
    b = true
    if a, ok := b.(bool); !ok {
        fmt.Println("Problem!")
    }
}
```

Yields this error in the golang playground:

```
tmp/sandbox791966413/main.go:11:10: a declared and not used
tmp/sandbox791966413/main.go:14:21: a declared and not used
```

This is confusing because of what we read in the short variable declaration [golang docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may
>   redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in
>   the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function
>   body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables
>   is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a
>   multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a
>   new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

So, my questions:

1. Why can't I redeclare the variable in the code snippet above?
2. Supposing I really can't, what I'd *really* like to do is find
   a way to populate variables with the output of functions while
   checking the error in a more concise way. So **is there any way 
   to improve on the following form for getting a value out of an
   error-able function?**

   ```
   var A RealType
   if newA, err := SomeFunc(); err != nil {
       return err
   } else {
       A = newA
   }
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because you are using the short variable declaration in an `if` initialization statement, which introduces a new scope.

Rather than this, where `a` is a new variable that shadows the existing one:

```
if a, ok := b.(bool); !ok {
    fmt.Println("Problem!")
}
```

you could do this, where `a` is redeclared:

```
a, ok := b.(bool)
if !ok {
    fmt.Println("Problem!")
}
```

This works because `ok` is a new variable, so you can redeclare `a` and the passage you quoted is in effect.

Similarly, your second code snippet could be written as:

```
A, err := SomeFunc()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Comment: I suppose that is a bit shorter, using short decls outside the if.

Answer (score 2):

You did redeclare the variable, that is the problem. When you redeclare a variable, it is a different variable. This is known as "shadowing".

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    // original a.
    var a bool
    var b interface{}
    b = true
    // redeclared a here. This is a a'
    if a, ok := b.(bool); !ok {
        // a' will last until the end of this block
        fmt.Println("Problem!")
    }
    // a' is gone. So using a here would get the original a.
}
```

---

As for your second question. That code looks great. I would probably switch it to if err == nil (and swap the if and else blocks). But that is a style thing.

Comment: "When you redeclare a variable, it is a different variable. " This is true only if the scope is different. When we redeclare a variable in the same scope, it just assigns a new value to the original.

Comment: According to the spec: "No identifier may be declared twice in the same block." So you are correct, it is the same variable, but that is because it cannot be redeclared. When a variable is redeclared, it is always done within an inner block (new scope). In this case, the new scope is the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

The error raised by the compiler is saying that both declarations of variable `a` are not being used.
You're actually declaring `a` twice, when using short declaration in the `if` condition you're creating a new scope that shadows the previous declaration of the variable.

The actual problem you're facing is that you're never using the variable value which, in Go, is considered a compile time error.

---

Regarding your second question, I think that the shortest way to get the value and check the error is to do something similar to this:

```
func main() {
    a, ok := someFunction()
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("Problem!")
    }
}
```